# insert into single table from multiple select

Tags: sql, insert

i need to insert 10 column(five pairs)into 2 column of another table.i try many ways like:

```
insert into table1(a,b) (select a1,b1 from table2),(select a2,b2 from table2)
```

all a,b columns are from same data type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` or `UNION` if you want to avoid duplicates.

```
insert into table1(a,b) 
select a1,b1 from table2
UNION ALL
select a2,b2 from table2;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/383739)**</kbd>